# SHBrowseForFolder закрывает окно

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, masm32

Не могу понять, почему SHBrowseDialog закрывает окно, причем само окно, которое должно быть открыто, не появляется. Помогите!

```
WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
    local rect:RECT
    local pt:POINT
    local bi:BROWSEINFO
    .IF uMsg==WM_DESTROY
        invoke PostQuitMessage,NULL
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_CREATE
        invoke CreateWindowEx, NULL, ADDR BtnClName, ADDR TextButton, WS_CHILD or BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON or WS_VISIBLE, 20, 20, 100, 50, hWnd, ButtonID, hInstance, 0
        mov hwndButton, eax
        invoke ShowWindow, hwndButton, SW_SHOWNORMAL
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_COMMAND
        mov eax, wParam
        .IF ax==ButtonID
            invoke SHBrowseForFolder, ADDR bi
        .ENDIF
    .ELSE
        invoke DefWindowProc,hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam   
        ret
    .ENDIF
    xor eax,eax
    ret
WndProc endp
end start
```

Comment: А где заполнение структуры BROWSEINFO? Как минимум, следует обнулить все её поля, прежде чем отправлять в функцию.

Comment: Спасибо! Дело было действительно в этом. Очень помогли!